# Taking image and splitting it into 3 equal pieces

Tags: javascript

I tried searching but didn't find a way to do specifically what I'm looking for. Not even sure it can be done but thought this wonderful community could help.

I want to take an image, split it into 3 equal pieces (left, middle, right) and then do what I'm gonna do with that.

Rather than just setting it up from the start as 3 pieces, I want to be able to take a container in the DOM, fill it with say... 5-6 images which then will be split up and placed into 3 equal sized containers.

I know how to do the rest easily, just not sure how you can take an image from the DOM in javascript to split it into 3 equal pieces.

I do not want to do canvas or svg, etc.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace the image with tree contiguous containers, where each container has the image as background. When you position the backgrounds properly you'll get the illusion of only one image.

Comment: I read that before but the only problem is eventually I wanted to make the images animate in a revolving type motion and settle on the next image. I guess I could do a large singular sprite with the images it just seems excessive. Was hoping there was a different or better way.

Comment: If you don't want to use canvas, that's the only way afaik. I made [a library](http://elclanrs.github.io/jq-tiles/) with this technique, so you can get pretty far.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of elclanrs. I was hoping there was programmatically a way to take the file and split it with something new like html 5 file system or blobs etc that I just didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what u actually mean. Do you want to make a container with 3 equals blocks in it? Or display image as 3 separate parts?

```
<style>
  .inner {
    float: left;
    width: 33%
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

If you want 3 images in them, you could set it as background and move it a little bit. For instance:

```
.inner {
    background-image: url('myimage.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.inner:nth-of-type(1) { background-position: 0px 0px; }
.inner:nth-of-type(2) { background-position: 0px -33% }
.inner:nth-of-type(3) { background-position: 0px -66px }
```

I can't tell more due to the lack of information.

Comment: This is a good answer but not exactly what I'm looking for. I did not provide enough detail, indeed. Eventually I want to animate the images in a revolving way to have them settle as a singular looking image. I think doing the images as a sprite will be too intensive as we are talking 1000x500 px per image.

Comment: Could you please describe one more time what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hard to give full details because it's something that isn't done on the web and I want to be the one to create it into a reusable library. Basically, to be able to take 6 images from one container in the dom, split each image into 3 equal pieces and reappend them into the DOM into 3 seperate containers for each piece to be manipulated how I need them to be.

Comment: You need only to **display them as** 3 images, or you actually mean to separate them and save them one by one to 3 different files? Best way would be not to cut anything, just to display them as such. Would take least of cpu time.

Comment: I only need to be able to take each image, split it into 3 equal pieces, and then re-insert into the DOM in 3 separate wrappers for each image. No need to save them, just put into DOM and manipulate in the DOM with animation etc.

Comment: What kind of animation are you talking about? Like .gif animation? or css3 animation with position/rotation changing?

Comment: Probably JavaScript animation but don't need help with any of that. Just need help figuring out how to split each image into 3 pieces with JavaScript

Comment: Realizing now that this is not going to be possible the way I'd like to do it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Realizing now that this is not going to be possible the way I'd like to do it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after all this information. One way could be JQuery [Crop Plugin](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/).

Without it, i think you'd have to create 3 elements and apply background to them.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.backgroundImage = "url('myimage.png');";
div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -33%";
document.body.append(div);
```

I can't think of anything else, sorry :C